# perl + install module ( problem: can't find gcc )

Tags: perl

please advice:

I want to install perl module
but after make command I get gcc - - command not found?
yael

# make

```
gcc -c   -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -    D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
```

# find / -name gcc

```
 /usr/lib/gcc

 # ls -l /usr/lib/gcc

 total 8
 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 27 11:36 i386-redhat-linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the gcc binary.  It's part of the `gcc` package:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/gcc
gcc-3.4.6-11.el4_8.1
```

It seems odd that you would not have that package installed, but try installing it with yum:

```
$ yum install gcc
```

that should go out to the standard repositories on the internet and grab the package and any dependencies and install them.

Comment: [please give me example how to install it from yum

Comment: Updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Thanx now its work